# Get Search Queries from UrlReferer

Tags: c#, asp.net, search-engine, url-parameters

I'm developing a website in ASP.Net 4. One of the requirements is to log search queries that people use to find our website. So, assuming that a URL parameter named "q" is present in Referrer, I've written the following code in my MasterPage's Page_Load:

```
if (!CookieHelper.HasCookie("mywebsite")) CookieHelper.CreateSearchCookie();
```

And my `CookieHelper` class is like this:

```
public class CookieHelper
{
  public static void CreateSearchCookie()
  {
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Query != null)
        {
            string q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Query).Get("q");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(q))
            {
                HttpCookie adcookie = new HttpCookie("mywebsite");
                adcookie.Value = q;
                adcookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(adcookie);
            }
        }
    }
  }

  public static bool HasCookie(string cookiename)
  {
    return (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookiename] != null);
  }
}
```

It seems ok at the first glance. I created a page to mimic a link from Google and worked like a charm. But it doesn't work on the host server. The reason is that when you search `blah blah` you see something like `www.google.com/?q=blah+blah` in your browser address bar. You expect clicking on your link in the results, will redirect to your site and you can grab the "q" parameter. But ,unfortunately, it is not true! Google, first redirects you to an address like:

```
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2F&ei=cks5Uof4G-aX0QXKhIGoCA&usg=AFQjCNEdmmYFpeRRRBiT_MGH5a1x9wUUlg&bvm=bv.52288139,d.d2k&cad=rja
```

and this will redirect to your website. As you can see the "q" parameter is empty this time! And my code gets an empty string and actually doesn't create the cookie (or whatever). 
I need to know if there is a way to solve this problem and get the real "q" value. The real search term user typed to find my website. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Google stopped passing the search keyword: 
http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/what-googles-keyword-data-grab-means-and-five-ways-around-it.html

Comment: Thanks. we already know it. The question is "if there is a way to get the real 'q' value"